Difference between  [ 3∣2 ] and  [3 ∣2] in a Binomial Tree Model
I'm studying conditional expectations in the context of a binomial tree model and encountered the following expressions:

$E[S_3 \mid \mathcal{F}_2]$: The expectation of the stock price at time 3 given the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}_2$, which represents all information up to time 2.
$E[S_3 \mid S_2]$: The expectation of the stock price at time 3 given only the stock price at time 2.

I understand that $\mathcal{F}_2$ contains more information than just $S_2$, and as a result, these expectations can differ. However, I'm struggling to fully grasp the implications of this difference.

Why are these two expectations generally unequal?
What is the significance of the difference in information between $\mathcal{F}_2$ and $ S_2$?
Is there a specific term or phenomenon in probability theory or financial mathematics that describes this situation?

I'm self-studying this topic for a presentation in my measure and probability class, so I'm a bit unsure about these concepts. Any insights or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

Source: Page 2 of this PDF

If $\mathcal F_2=\sigma (S_2)$, then both expectation are equal. Notice that $\mathbb E[S_3\mid S_2]$ is a short notation for $\mathbb E[S_3\mid \sigma (S_2)]$.

I don't quiet get the difference between F2 and σ(S2)

What is the significance of separating F2 and σ(S2)

$\sigma (S_2)$ is the smallest $\sigma -$algebra that makes $S_2$ measurable.

To contrive an example, suppose that we know the formula of the evolution of the stock price from time $2$ to time $3$ to be
$$S_3 = S_2 + X_2,$$
where the random variable $X_2$ is some other piece of market data which is known at time $2$, and which is independent of $S_2$. Then
$$E[S_3|\mathcal F_2] = S_2 + X_2$$
because we are using all information that we have at time $2$. However:
$$E[S_3|S_2] = S_2 + E[X_2]$$
because we are only using our knowledge of $S_2$. And knowing $S_2$ gives you no information about what $X_2$ is (since they are independent).

As expressed by example 3 on your pdf, the conditional expectations may differ because $\mathcal F_2$ contains information about the order of ups and downs, whereas $S_2$ is agnostic about that.
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(S_3\mid\mathcal F_2) &=\begin{cases}\ddots&:&\omega_1=H, \omega_2=H\\\ddots&:& \omega_1=H,\omega_2=T\\\ddots&:& \omega_1=T,\omega_2=H\\\ddots&:& \omega_1=T,\omega_2=H\end{cases}\\~\\\mathsf E(S_3\mid S_2)&=\begin{cases}\ddots&:&\omega_1=H, \omega_2=H\\\ddots&:& \omega_1=H,\omega_2=T\textbf{ OR }\omega_1=T,\omega_2=H\\\ddots&:& \omega_1=T,\omega_2=H\end{cases}\end{align}$$
